# GUI Window Does Not Resize as indicated

Tags: python, wxpython

I set the size in my panel, but it does not take action when I run the program. It just pops up small and I have to manually resize.

I have tried setting/initializing a frame, but when I do that it blocks any input. So I can no longer use my program. I have also tried numerous times to set it within the panel settings.

```
class CipherTexter(wx.Panel):
def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, size=(5000, 5000))
    #wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent,  size=(5000, 5000))
    self.cipherText = wx.StaticText(self, label="Cipher Texter ", pos=(20, 30))
```

…

```
app = wx.App(False)
frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "The SS Cipher")
panel = CipherTexter(frame)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

When I first open the application, I get this. I would like to be able to see the whole thing instead of having to manually resize it.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the "panel" within the "frame".
Here is a mock up of what is, I suppose, your required starting point.

```
import wx

class CipherTexter(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title,  size=(1000, 600))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        cipherText = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Cipher Texter ", pos=(20, 30))
        encryptorText = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Encryptor ", pos=(20, 70))
        decryptorText = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Decryptor ", pos=(20, 100))
        self.cipher = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE, size=(400,400), pos=(400, 30))
        self.encryptor = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, size=(100,30), pos=(200, 70))
        self.decryptor = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, size=(100,30), pos=(200, 100))
        self.encrypt = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Encrypt", pos=(20, 140))
        self.decrypt = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Decrypt", pos=(20, 180))
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour('white')
        self.encrypt.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.encryptNow)
        self.decrypt.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.decryptNow)
        self.Show()

    def encryptNow(self, event):
        print("Encrypting")
        cipher = self.cipher.GetValue()
        encryptor = self.encryptor.GetValue()
        print(cipher)
        print("with ", encryptor)

    def decryptNow(self, event):
        print("De-Encrypting")
        cipher = self.cipher.GetValue()
        decryptor = self.decryptor.GetValue()
        print(cipher)
        print("with ", decryptor)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = CipherTexter(None, "The SS Cipher")
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]